# failing to update xcode

Tags: xcode, installation

Im trying to update Xcode by downloading the diskimage from the mac developer homepage. After installing it I try to drag and drop it to the applications folder. And so replacing the old version with the new one.

I get the following error:
"Operation could not be completed because some items had to be skipped. Go to File> Get Info for each file, make sure the check box "Locked" is unchecked and then look under the Sharing & Permissions. When you are sure that objects are not locked and are not marked as "Read Only" or "No Access" try again."

This is what "ls -l" of xcode shows me:

drwxrwxrwx   3 root            wheel   102 19 Aug  2012 Xcode.app

I have tried to chown the app. but failed and it seems not to be the appropriate thing to do. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: are you administrator?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yes. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Try manually removing all xcode/developer directories and try again

Comment: @AnoopVaidya  Really? Do you mean the whole dir or just the contents?

Comment: if that way it is not happing try all other ways too

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Do you mean trying to remove all dirs, one by one?

Comment: only specific to xcode

Comment: @AnoopVaidya haha, yes of course, but I mean to say, all dir in the Xcode app?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I tried to do what you said but it did not work, now I dont have a developer dir, :-(. Is there a way to reinstall it?.... Well Im trying now, to throw the old app in the trashbin and reinstalling it. Fingers crossed.

Comment: restart you mac and try reinstalling xcode

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Already did it. This was actually the only solution. If you post it as an answer I will accept it as an answer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your tried to install XCode and in between the installation failed. Now you are stuck as neither older version nor newer is running on your machine.

**Delete all the directories manually which are related to XCode.** Then restart your machine and re-install it.